# Picking correct function to run

Tags: php

I currently have 2 functions, one is LoginButton(); and the other is LogoutButton(); and I also have an if statement like this:

```
If (CODE){

}else{

}
```

I want the function to be called at a specific place as I want the buttons to appear there. So how can I assign the functions to a variable so I can call the correct one later on?

I am currently referencing the functions like this:

```
<?php echo logoutbutton(); ?>
<?php echo loginbutton(); ?>
```

But I only want the correct one showing.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I would suggest use sessions here, if session exist then show logout button if not then show login button.

Comment: This is what I have done, but I want to do it so i can reference the function later, so if I call the function loginbutton(); it appears in the far top left, but I want it ran in the footer, so I want to be able to reference it at the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$button = (condition) ? loginbutton() : logoutbutton();
```

The above expression is equal to:

```
$function;
if (condition) {
    $button = loginbutton();
}
else {
    $button = logoutbutton();
}
```

Comment: I had tried that already, but then if I do <?php echo $button; ?> in the footer nothing appears.

Comment: Show me some code. I can't help you if I don't know what's going on in your file. I can only guess at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use session here to keep track of user has logged in or not. Something like this

```
$function = (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) ? logoutbutton() : loginbutton();
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work like this: <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) ? logoutbutton() : loginbutton(); ?>

Comment: Glad to hear that. Can you please accept my answer then? if it helped you to solve your query.